# How to use smaller font size in a GitHub table?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown, readme

How to use a smaller font size in a GitHub readme.md?

I am trying to figure out how to use smaller text in the GitHub readme.

More specifically, I created a table and I want the font size to be smaller for this table.

I saw somewhere people recommended to use  which I tried and does not work.

Table:

```
| Embedding       | Script        |
|-----------------|---------------|
| word2Vec        | abc.sh        |
| code2Vec        | cde.sh        |
```

The intention is to make the font size for the complete table smaller.

Can anyone please advise me what's the workaround?

Comment: Please post your existing Markdown, and preferably a link to it on a public GitHub page.

Comment: @Dai I have posted my markdown

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Github doesn't allow inline-`style`s or `class`es. A workaround is to wrap `sub` tag around each element.

| Embedding | Script |
| --- | --- |
| word2Vec | <sub>abc.sh</sub> |
| code2Vec | cde.sh |

Comment: This is terrible for accessibility, since `sub` has a specific semantic meaning, which isn't "make this text smaller".

Comment: @bkk2204: Yes you are correct. I was pointing out the only way I know of doing it in a github readme.md

Comment: @bk2204 what are the accessibility implications of using the `sub` tag?

Comment: Screen readers rely on the semantic meaning to read the page.  For example, they might read "subscript" in such a case, or otherwise read the text in a different way.  In addition, making the text smaller when someone has specifically set it to be larger so that they can read it prevents them from seeing it at all.

Comment: @bk2204: you are persisting with that argument for a readme.md on a github page? :)

Comment: Yes, it is very definitely an accessibility problem.  Even if you don't think the README is important enough, it causes problems for people, including people I have known and worked with.  Blind people and people with vision problems should be able to experience the Internet at its best without people carelessly or intentionally causing problems for them.

Answer (score 16):

If you layer them like this, `<sub><sup>combining the two tags</sup></sub>`, you get tiny text that's almost in line with the normal text. Nice for making very small caveats to your answers!

Comment: wrap the text with this =>  [   <sub><sup>combining the two tags</sup></sub>  ]

Answer (score 2):

GitHub doesn't permit you to adjust font sizes, styles, or colors when it renders Markdown.  That's because the text needs to be legible on all sorts of systems with all sorts of font sizes and in both light and dark mode.

Just because you can read and see smaller text in your table does not mean that others can (I know people who have vision problems and cannot), and for legal reasons as well as general good site design, GitHub wants its site to be accessible for all users on all platforms.

In addition, allowing user-provided styles has potential security and abuse implications, which is another reason it's not allowed.  For example, users could include tiny, invisible, or otherwise unreadable text to game search result rankings or include other objectionable text that would be visible to computers but not to humans.

Comment: This is misguided. E.g. you can have `<sup>` and `<sub>` all right as a counter-example: it would be very silly to disable their font size adjustments for _everyone_ just because _some_ of us have limited eyesight. CSS stylesheets have been just the perfect tool to handle diverse accessibility requirements for decades now. And they don't need to be "user-provided", the site can provide curated sheets (there is zero added risk with that), so you can have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: GitHub takes into account things like `sup` and `sub` when choosing font sizes so that those are readable when used in the context of the superscript or subscript those represent.  I agree CSS is a great tool for adjusting font sizes and other styling concerns.  However, nobody rendering user-generated HTML allows CSS or JavaScript for security reasons unless they want a CVE.  Also, Markdown is a document language, not a presentation language, so CSS and other styling doesn't belong in a pure-Markdown document at all.